# Does the Mapbox Sheet Mapper plugin only read Google Sheet column data as strings?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am using Mapbox's Sheet Mapper plugin and trying to use a data step expression to colour circles using numbers in a column labelled "Sales Value" in the Google Sheet.

This is the data step expression I'm trying:

"circle-color": [
"step",
["get", "Sales Value"],
"#51bbd6",
100,
"#f1f075",
2000,
"#f28cb1"
]

(I am following the Create and Style Clusters demo for the step expression https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/)

However, the circles are black, not coloured, and the message is "Expected value to be of type number, but found string instead."

The "Sales Value" column in my Google Sheet is definitely formatted as numbers, e.g. 2000.

Does this mean that the Sheet Mapper plugin treats all Google Sheet data as strings?

Is there anything I can do to make the Mapbox data expression understand the column data as numbers not strings?

Thank you to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out. Needed to add an explicit instruction "to-number" as part of the expression. This works:

"circle-color": [
"step",
["to-number", ["get", "Sales Value"]],
"#51bbd6",
100,
"#f1f075",
2000,
"#f28cb1"
]